# Is it possible in Spring Security to use form login if CAS is not available?

Tags: spring-security, cas

everybody!

In my project I use SSO with CAS. But what if the CAS-server is down? 
I want a user to be able to login with a simple login/password form when CAS is not available.

Is it possible to configure Spring Security that way?
What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Having said that you use SSO and wanting to use Spring Security as a backup when CAS is down, I am trying to understand how the SSO part will work with spring security. You can certainly implement your own version of single sign on with spring security using oauth2 services or your own implementation. If you did implement something like that, it brings up a question of redundant SSO services, managing them and maintaining them.

CAS, to my understanding, is primarily used for SSO purpose and has its own set of configuration. I am sure, you would have cassified your application for this purpose as well.

Is CAS server being down is an issue, I would suggest setting up a backup or standby for CAS server or building your own single sign on solution. I am trying to say that it is "either or" is more recommended than "having both"